# Error:(8, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How can I resolve this problem?

At first the problem was, I would like to use ActivityCompat class for ask permission. After it shown me the AdroidStudio, the class cannot be resolved to a type but, the Support Repository already installed...

I upgraded the AndroidStudio to 2.3 from 2.2 after show me:
Error:(8, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' 
Currently here are the possible solutions by Android Studio:

- 'Sensors' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that
  does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
  (Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.0 and sync project)
- The project 'Sensors' may be using a version of Gradle that does not
  contain the method. (Gradle settings)
- The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. (Apply Gradle plugin)

What is the right solution for this? I tried each but not resolve the problem.

Here is the dependencies of build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0"` out of your top-level `build.gradle` file and into the module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`) and its `dependencies` closure.

Comment: Now I'm back to my original problem :-) ActivityCompat does not exists.

The  dependencies are:
        compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'

Comment: @Laszlo: `appcompat-v7` should be pulling in `support-compat`, where `ActivityCompat` resides. However, I have seen some strange behavior there recently. Try adding another dependency, alongside the two that you have, for `com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0`, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you of your explanation I successfully resolved the problem with your help! Thanks!